# Why does this method return three values?

Tags: ruby

I have following Ruby programm:

```
def swap (a,b)
   return a,b = b,a
end

puts swap(5,3)
```

I expected the output.

```
3
5
```

But I get.

```
5
3
5
```

What's the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: You can just use `return b,a`. The assignment here is completely pointless as the local variables are garbage collected as soon as the method finishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this method return three values?

It's because of the `return` statement, Ruby tries to interpret the right-hand side as an *array* and your code:

```
return a,b = b,a
```

gets evaluated as: (parentheses added for clarity)

```
return [a, (b=b), a]
```

i.e. a 3-element array `[a, b, a]` (assigning `b` to itself does nothing)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the keyword `return`. It is actually doing: return a, (b), a. Where (b = b)

```
def swap(a,b)
  a, b = b, a
end

puts swap(5,3)
```

Output

```
=> 3, 5
```

Comment: Thank you. But why can't I use return here? Doesn't return the expression  the value of the assignment a,b=b,a?

Answer (score 0):

In your program: in swap function the return you have given is  `return a,b = b,a`
remove `a,b`and diretcly write `return b,a`.
you will get your expected output.
Reason:
in `return a,b = b,a` is return first the value of `a` then executing `b=b,a`.
Hope this might help you out

```
def swap (a,b)
   return b,a
end

puts swap(5,3)
```

Output

```
3
5
```